# Magento 2, DI & Composer

Tags: magento2, composer, di

I would like to know if all dependency injections used in a module have to be declared in the "module dependencies".

And, in this case, as "soft" dependencies (in module.xml file), as "hard" dependencies (in composer.json file) or both?

In my studies I learned they have to be added in composer.json file.. am I right?

Comment: have you gone through dev guide for magento 2 ? http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/depend-inj.html  it will give you right idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use any class/interface from a module other than your's you need to declare that in `composer.json`.
`module.xml` does not contain dependencies.
It only holds the list of modules that should be loaded before your module. 
Even if you add there a module that does not exist, your module will still run properly.

Comment: Ok, the answer is: simplifying, I have to add DI in composer file.

For **module.xml** I know "it only holds the list of modules that should be loaded before your module. Even if you add there a module that does not exist, your module will still run properly" but in Magento documentation it is known as "_Soft Dependency_".
In any case, I discovered it is useless to insert add DI in module.xml..